# how can I draw rectangle on every page and a image on titlepage?

Tags: graphics, header-footer, backgrounds

i need to do the following design for a class in latex. I know how to format stuff but I don't know how to draw the gray areas, footer and the image.

**What I got already:**

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  titlepage,
  footheight=12pt,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[page]{totalcount}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=15mm,
 right=15mm,
 top=15mm,
 bottom=15mm,
 }

\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{rubgray}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{rubblue}{HTML}{003560}
\definecolor{rubgreen}{HTML}{8dae10}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{4cm}
            {\Huge \textbf{ \textcolor{rubgray}{ABSCHLUSSBERICHT}}}
            \\
            \vspace*{1cm}
            {\Large \textbf{ \textcolor{rubblue}{Funktionsweise und Datenschutzgefährdung der Smart Border Systeme}}}
            \\
            \vspace*{2cm}
            Abschlussbericht der Projektarbeit für das Fach\\
            \textbf{Datenschutz WS 16/17}\\
            Im Studienfach\\
            \textbf{    B.Sc. Angewandte Informatik}
        \end{center}
        \vfill
        \begin{flushright}
            \textbf{Saif Al-Dilaimi (xxx)} \\
            \textcolor{rubblue}{\textbf{RUHR-UNIVERSITÄT} BOCHUM} \\
            Institut für Neuroinformatik \\
            Ruhr-Universität Bochum \\
            Universitätsstraße 150 \\
            44801 Bochum
        \end{flushright}
    \end{titlepage}

    \begin{flushleft}
    lölöö           
    \end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

The structure of my page should have this design:

**1. Page:**

[image]

**2, 3, ... Page:**

[image]

as you see the **first page** has those gray areas and a image (the top right RUB logo) but no footer with the document title.

on the **seconde page and after** the image is gone but the gray areas and the footer is now there.

I really hope you guys can help..

Comment: Welcome! There isn't room with the page dimensions you've defined.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Look where the page numbers end up. That's where your footer is.

Comment: This looks like the sort of thing for which RUB probably already has a LaTeX template. You're more likely to get exactly what you need by asking them for it rather than trying to duplicate their style from scratch.

Comment: I asked already the design division and they don't have a latex template :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use package `scrlayer-scrpage` not only for the footer but also to define new layers for the rules at the bottom and the right margin. These new layers can be added to all page styles including `empty`. And for the logo on the title page a new layer page style `titlepage` can be used.

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  titlepage,
  ngerman,
  footheight=15pt,
  headheight=15pt,
  oneside% seems to be a onesided layout
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[page]{totalcount}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
     total={170mm,257mm}
 }
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}

%% footer
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength\footheight{15pt}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ifoot*{\pagemark}
\cfoot*{Center}
\ofoot*{Right}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\small}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\small}

\renewcommand\pagemark{{%
    \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\pagename}}
    \usekomafont{pagenumber}%
    \thepage/\totalpages
}}

%% rules on every page
\DeclareNewLayer[
    background,
    bottommargin,
    addvoffset=-\footheight,
    addvoffset=-.5ex,
    mode=picture,
    contents=\putUL{\textcolor{Silver}{\rule[-\layerheight]{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}}
]{bottomrule}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=bottomrule,
    textarea,
    voffset=0pt,
    height=\paperheight,
    addhoffset=\textwidth,
    addhoffset=1ex
]{rightrule}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{bottomrule,rightrule}

%% logo on the title page
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=rightrule,
    contents=\putUL{\raisebox{-\height}{\makebox[5mm][r]{\includegraphics[scale=.7]{example-grid-100x100bp}}}}
]{titlepagelogo}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlepagelogo}
%%

\definecolor{rubgray}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{rubblue}{HTML}{003560}
\definecolor{rubgreen}{HTML}{8dae10}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \thispagestyle{titlepage}
  \begin{center}
    \vspace*{4cm}
    {\Huge \textbf{ \textcolor{rubgray}{ABSCHLUSSBERICHT}}}
    \\
    \vspace*{1cm}
    {\Large \textbf{ \textcolor{rubblue}{Funktionsweise und Datenschutzgefährdung der Smart Border Systeme}}}
    \\
    \vspace*{2cm}
    Abschlussbericht der Projektarbeit für das Fach\\
    \textbf{Datenschutz WS 16/17}\\
    Im Studienfach\\
    \textbf{    B.Sc. Angewandte Informatik}
  \end{center}
  \vfill
  \begin{flushright}
    \textbf{Saif Al-Dilaimi (xxx)} \\
    \textcolor{rubblue}{\textbf{RUHR-UNIVERSITÄT} BOCHUM} \\
    Institut für Neuroinformatik \\
    Ruhr-Universität Bochum \\
    Universitätsstraße 150 \\
    44801 Bochum
  \end{flushright}
\end{titlepage}

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: this answer is perfect and i'm using it! Your approach is a lot cleaner! thx!

Comment: Hey, any idea on that one ? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402540/supporting-landscape-mode-with-following-design

Answer (score 4):

The logo doesn't look very good because it is currently grey-on-grey and you will need to adjust the `xshift` appropriately for your image. However, that should be easy enough.

This answer uses:

- Ti*k*Z to create the grey background;
- `tikzpagenodes` to place the image and grey background;
- `everypage` to add the image and background on the appropriate pages;
- `scrlayer-scrpage` to configure the footer.

I've adjusted the `geometry` settings in response to `scrlayer-scrpage`s complaints and the need to abide by the dictates of physical reality. I've left the size of the text block as was, set `headheight` according to the warnings (otherwise, it gets changed and causes inconsistent layout. I don't know why it won't let it be `0pt` but it won't.) I've set `\footheight` directly in the same way. (Again, otherwise, the layout will be inconsistent. Adjust `footskip` in the settings as desired. I've used `10mm`. Use `verbose` and/or `showframe` to have `geometry` tell you what it is doing and read the console output like a hawk for warnings from `geometry`, KOMA and/or `scrlayer-scrpage`. Adjust the `pageheadfoot` disposition as required. I've used small sans-serif as an example.

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  titlepage,
  ngerman,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[page]{totalcount}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 total={170mm,257mm},
 headheight=15pt,
 marginratio=1:1,
 marginparwidth=0pt,
 marginparsep=0pt,
 footskip=10mm,
 }
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{everypage,tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength\footheight{15pt}
\ohead{}
\chead{}
\ihead{}
\ofoot{Out here.}
\cfoot{This is the footer for every page but the first of this document.}
\ifoot{In here.}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\small}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay]{%
    \fill [Silver] (current page.north east) |- (current page.south west) |- ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=-2.5mm]current page text area.south east) |- cycle;
  }%
}

\definecolor{rubgray}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{rubblue}{HTML}{003560}
\definecolor{rubgreen}{HTML}{8dae10}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{center}
    \vspace*{4cm}
    {\Huge \textbf{ \textcolor{rubgray}{ABSCHLUSSBERICHT}}}
    \\
    \vspace*{1cm}
    {\Large \textbf{ \textcolor{rubblue}{Funktionsweise und Datenschutzgefährdung der Smart Border Systeme}}}
    \\
    \vspace*{2cm}
    Abschlussbericht der Projektarbeit für das Fach\\
    \textbf{Datenschutz WS 16/17}\\
    Im Studienfach\\
    \textbf{    B.Sc. Angewandte Informatik}
  \end{center}
  \vfill
  \begin{flushright}
    \textbf{Saif Al-Dilaimi (xxx)} \\
    \textcolor{rubblue}{\textbf{RUHR-UNIVERSITÄT} BOCHUM} \\
    Institut für Neuroinformatik \\
    Ruhr-Universität Bochum \\
    Universitätsstraße 150 \\
    44801 Bochum
  \end{flushright}
  \AddThispageHook{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\node [anchor=north, xshift=-5mm, inner sep=0pt] at (current page text area.east |- current page.north) {\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image-golden-upright}};
    }%
  }%
\end{titlepage}

\kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: double-page]

[image: titlepage]

Comment: Omg, this looks perfect! I have to check it out this evening(early morning here) because I'm not home.

Comment: I had time to test it and it works as expected! thanks a lot. Altough I prefer the answer of @esdd because the rules and layers simplify a lot! I will accept yours because you was first posting a working solution but I will his example.. thx to you both!

Comment: @SaifDeen Please accept esdd's answer rather than mine. It doesn't matter who answered first. What matters is which answer is better or most helpful. esdd's is better and helped you most.

Comment: Hey any idea on that one? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402540/supporting-landscape-mode-with-following-design

Comment: @SaifDeen Looks like you got good answers already. :)