# Supporting landscape mode with following design

Tags: graphics, header-footer, backgrounds, scrlayer-scrpage

Following up to that [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342128/how-can-i-draw-rectangle-on-every-page-and-a-image-on-titlepage) I would like to know how to elegantly change some pages into landscape mode to display a diagram or so. Especially it should support the design which I posted in my original question (marked Answer)! Basically when in landscape the height/width of the grey areas should depend on the page orientation. I'm just not sure how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

Optional: It would be awesome if I can create new pages that have no grey areas by a command or so.

Comment: I think you don't have to adapt the page design, just use `sidecap` package (or something similar) to insert rotated captions.

Comment: Do you have any reference to a wiki or a working example to my situation?

Comment: As far as I see it has nothing to do with my question because I'm talking about a page layout and not about captions..

Comment: For me the question currently is somehow unclear. Please be more precise in the description of what you want. A MWE that illustrates your current problem would be very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need rotated output in the preview but only rotation of, e.g., a figure even a simple `\rotatebox` could be enough:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  titlepage,
  ngerman,
  footheight=15pt,
  headheight=15pt,
  oneside% seems to be a onesided layout
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[page]{totalcount}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={170mm,257mm}}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}

%% footer
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength\footheight{15pt}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ifoot*{\pagemark}
\cfoot*{Center}
\ofoot*{Right}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\small}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\small}

\renewcommand\pagemark{{%
    \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\pagename}}
    \usekomafont{pagenumber}%
    \thepage/\totalpages
}}

%% rules on every page
\DeclareNewLayer[
    background,
    bottommargin,
    addvoffset=-\footheight,
    addvoffset=-.5ex,
    mode=picture,
    contents=\putUL{\textcolor{Silver}{\rule[-\layerheight]{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}}
]{bottomrule}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=bottomrule,
    textarea,
    voffset=0pt,
    height=\paperheight,
    addhoffset=\textwidth,
    addhoffset=1ex
]{rightrule}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{bottomrule,rightrule}

%% logo on the title page
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=rightrule,
    contents=\putUL{\raisebox{-\height}{\makebox[5mm][r]{\includegraphics[scale=.7]{example-grid-100x100bp}}}}
]{titlepagelogo}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlepagelogo}
%%

\definecolor{rubgray}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{rubblue}{HTML}{003560}
\definecolor{rubgreen}{HTML}{8dae10}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \thispagestyle{titlepage}
  \begin{center}
    \vspace*{4cm}
    {\Huge \textbf{ \textcolor{rubgray}{ABSCHLUSSBERICHT}}}
    \\
    \vspace*{1cm}
    {\Large \textbf{ \textcolor{rubblue}{Funktionsweise und Datenschutzgefährdung der Smart Border Systeme}}}
    \\
    \vspace*{2cm}
    Abschlussbericht der Projektarbeit für das Fach\\
    \textbf{Datenschutz WS 16/17}\\
    Im Studienfach\\
    \textbf{    B.Sc. Angewandte Informatik}
  \end{center}
  \vfill
  \begin{flushright}
    \textbf{Saif Al-Dilaimi (xxx)} \\
    \textcolor{rubblue}{\textbf{RUHR-UNIVERSITÄT} BOCHUM} \\
    Institut für Neuroinformatik \\
    Ruhr-Universität Bochum \\
    Universitätsstraße 150 \\
    44801 Bochum
  \end{flushright}
\end{titlepage}

\blinddocument

\begin{figure}
  \rotatebox{90}{%
    \parbox[c][\textwidth][c]{\textheight}{%
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth,height=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
      \caption{What's the problem?}
  }}%
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: figure with rotatebox]

---

And if you want to have real landscape pages inside the portrait document, you can combine `typearea`'s options `paper=landscape` and `paper=portrait` with `geometry`'s `\newgeometry` command using `typearea`'s option `usegeometry`:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  titlepage,
  ngerman,
  footheight=15pt,
  headheight=15pt,
  usegeometry,
  oneside% seems to be a onesided layout
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[page]{totalcount}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\newgeometry{total={170mm,257mm}}}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}

%% footer
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength\footheight{15pt}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ifoot*{\pagemark}
\cfoot*{Center}
\ofoot*{Right}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\small}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\small}

\renewcommand\pagemark{{%
    \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\pagename}}
    \usekomafont{pagenumber}%
    \thepage/\totalpages
}}

%% rules on every page
\DeclareNewLayer[
    background,
    bottommargin,
    addvoffset=-\footheight,
    addvoffset=-.5ex,
    mode=picture,
    contents=\putUL{\textcolor{Silver}{\rule[-\layerheight]{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}}
]{bottomrule}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=bottomrule,
    textarea,
    voffset=0pt,
    height=\paperheight,
    addhoffset=\textwidth,
    addhoffset=1ex
]{rightrule}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{bottomrule,rightrule}

%% logo on the title page
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=rightrule,
    contents=\putUL{\raisebox{-\height}{\makebox[5mm][r]{\includegraphics[scale=.7]{example-grid-100x100bp}}}}
]{titlepagelogo}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlepagelogo}
%%

\definecolor{rubgray}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{rubblue}{HTML}{003560}
\definecolor{rubgreen}{HTML}{8dae10}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \thispagestyle{titlepage}
  \begin{center}
    \vspace*{4cm}
    {\Huge \textbf{ \textcolor{rubgray}{ABSCHLUSSBERICHT}}}
    \\
    \vspace*{1cm}
    {\Large \textbf{ \textcolor{rubblue}{Funktionsweise und Datenschutzgefährdung der Smart Border Systeme}}}
    \\
    \vspace*{2cm}
    Abschlussbericht der Projektarbeit für das Fach\\
    \textbf{Datenschutz WS 16/17}\\
    Im Studienfach\\
    \textbf{    B.Sc. Angewandte Informatik}
  \end{center}
  \vfill
  \begin{flushright}
    \textbf{Saif Al-Dilaimi (xxx)} \\
    \textcolor{rubblue}{\textbf{RUHR-UNIVERSITÄT} BOCHUM} \\
    Institut für Neuroinformatik \\
    Ruhr-Universität Bochum \\
    Universitätsstraße 150 \\
    44801 Bochum
  \end{flushright}
\end{titlepage}

\blinddocument

\cleardoubleoddpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=current}
\newgeometry{total={257mm,170mm}}
\blindtext[2]

\cleardoubleoddpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,DIV=current}
\newgeometry{total={170mm,257mm}}
\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to switch often, you can store the setting once, using `typearea`'s `\storeareas` and use the stored settings often:

```
\storeareas\useportrait
\cleardoubleoddpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=current}
\newgeometry{total={257mm,170mm}}
\storeareas\uselandscape
\blindtext[2]

\cleardoubleoddpage\useportrait
\blindtext[2]

\cleardoubleoddpage\uselandscape
\blindtext[2]

\cleardoubleoddpage\useportrait
\blindtext[2]

\cleardoubleoddpage\uselandscape
\blindtext[2]

\cleardoubleoddpage\useportrait
\blindtext[2]
```

or you can define two commands in the document preamble:

```
\newcommand*{\useportrait}{%
  \cleardoubleoddpage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,DIV=current}%
  \newgeometry{total={170mm,257mm}}%
}

\newcommand*{\uselandscape}{%
  \cleardoubleoddpage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=current}%
  \newgeometry{total={257mm,170mm}}%
}
```

and use these commands to switch:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  titlepage,
  ngerman,
  footheight=15pt,
  headheight=15pt,
  usegeometry,
  oneside% seems to be a onesided layout
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[page]{totalcount}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcommand*{\useportrait}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,DIV=current}%
  \newgeometry{total={170mm,257mm}}%
}
\newcommand*{\uselandscape}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=current}%
  \newgeometry{total={257mm,170mm}}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\useportrait}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}

%% footer
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength\footheight{15pt}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ifoot*{\pagemark}
\cfoot*{Center}
\ofoot*{Right}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\small}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\small}

\renewcommand\pagemark{{%
    \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\pagename}}
    \usekomafont{pagenumber}%
    \thepage/\totalpages
}}

%% rules on every page
\DeclareNewLayer[
    background,
    bottommargin,
    addvoffset=-\footheight,
    addvoffset=-.5ex,
    mode=picture,
    contents=\putUL{\textcolor{Silver}{\rule[-\layerheight]{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}}
]{bottomrule}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=bottomrule,
    textarea,
    voffset=0pt,
    height=\paperheight,
    addhoffset=\textwidth,
    addhoffset=1ex
]{rightrule}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{bottomrule,rightrule}

%% logo on the title page
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=rightrule,
    contents=\putUL{\raisebox{-\height}{\makebox[5mm][r]{\includegraphics[scale=.7]{example-grid-100x100bp}}}}
]{titlepagelogo}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlepagelogo}
%%

\definecolor{rubgray}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{rubblue}{HTML}{003560}
\definecolor{rubgreen}{HTML}{8dae10}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \thispagestyle{titlepage}
  \begin{center}
    \vspace*{4cm}
    {\Huge \textbf{ \textcolor{rubgray}{ABSCHLUSSBERICHT}}}
    \\
    \vspace*{1cm}
    {\Large \textbf{ \textcolor{rubblue}{Funktionsweise und Datenschutzgefährdung der Smart Border Systeme}}}
    \\
    \vspace*{2cm}
    Abschlussbericht der Projektarbeit für das Fach\\
    \textbf{Datenschutz WS 16/17}\\
    Im Studienfach\\
    \textbf{    B.Sc. Angewandte Informatik}
  \end{center}
  \vfill
  \begin{flushright}
    \textbf{Saif Al-Dilaimi (xxx)} \\
    \textcolor{rubblue}{\textbf{RUHR-UNIVERSITÄT} BOCHUM} \\
    Institut für Neuroinformatik \\
    Ruhr-Universität Bochum \\
    Universitätsstraße 150 \\
    44801 Bochum
  \end{flushright}
\end{titlepage}

\blinddocument

\uselandscape
\blindtext[2]

\useportrait
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: looks great! Is there a way to avoid changing the geometry each time        ?

Comment: @SaifDeen You can use `\storeareas` to store them once and use them often. Or you can define two commands in the document preamble.

Comment: awesome, I have to go with your answer altough both are excellent. But you have also solved it according my wishes. @esdd gave also an answer to my optional question. Too bad I cant set both as correct answer.

Comment: I got an issue: when I'm using the commands texmaker says that \landscape and \potrait are already defined. If I change name to \uselandscape the geometry changes but it stays in potrait mode. See: https://imgur.com/a/Iv6yR

Comment: `\landscape` is also defined by package `pdflscape` or package `lscape`. There was a little typo in the landscape switch: it should be `paper=landscape`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no MWE in the question, so I do not know what you are meaning by landscape mode. Maybe you want to use the environment `landscape` provided by package `pdflscape`? I also do not understand what the desired layout is.

If you want to get

[image]

you can load package `scrhack`.

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  titlepage,
  ngerman,
  footheight=15pt,
  headheight=15pt,
  oneside% seems to be a onesided layout
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrhack}% <- added
\usepackage{pdflscape}% <- added
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[page]{totalcount}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
     total={170mm,257mm}
 }
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}

%% footer
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength\footheight{15pt}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ifoot*{\pagemark}
\cfoot*{Center}
\ofoot*{Right}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\small}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\small}

\renewcommand\pagemark{{%
    \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\pagename}}
    \usekomafont{pagenumber}%
    \thepage/\totalpages
}}

%% rules on every page
\DeclareNewLayer[
    background,
    bottommargin,
    addvoffset=-\footheight,
    addvoffset=-.5ex,
    mode=picture,
    contents=\putUL{\textcolor{Silver}{\rule[-\layerheight]{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}}
]{bottomrule}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=bottomrule,
    textarea,
    voffset=0pt,
    height=\paperheight,
    addhoffset=\textwidth,
    addhoffset=1ex
]{rightrule}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{bottomrule,rightrule}

%% logo on the title page
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=rightrule,
    contents=\putUL{\raisebox{-\height}{\makebox[5mm][r]{\includegraphics[scale=.7]{example-grid-100x100bp}}}}
]{titlepagelogo}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlepagelogo}
%%

\definecolor{rubgray}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{rubblue}{HTML}{003560}
\definecolor{rubgreen}{HTML}{8dae10}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \thispagestyle{titlepage}
  \begin{center}
    \vspace*{4cm}
    {\Huge \textbf{ \textcolor{rubgray}{ABSCHLUSSBERICHT}}}
    \\
    \vspace*{1cm}
    {\Large \textbf{ \textcolor{rubblue}{Funktionsweise und Datenschutzgefährdung der Smart Border Systeme}}}
    \\
    \vspace*{2cm}
    Abschlussbericht der Projektarbeit für das Fach\\
    \textbf{Datenschutz WS 16/17}\\
    Im Studienfach\\
    \textbf{    B.Sc. Angewandte Informatik}
  \end{center}
  \vfill
  \begin{flushright}
    \textbf{Saif Al-Dilaimi (xxx)} \\
    \textcolor{rubblue}{\textbf{RUHR-UNIVERSITÄT} BOCHUM} \\
    Institut für Neuroinformatik \\
    Ruhr-Universität Bochum \\
    Universitätsstraße 150 \\
    44801 Bochum
  \end{flushright}
\end{titlepage}

\blinddocument
\begin{landscape}
\Blindtext
\end{landscape}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

Regarding your second question: You can define commands which add or remove layers from a page style.

```
\newcommand*\AddRulesToPageStyles{%
  \IfLayerAtPageStyle{@everystyle@}{bottomrule}{}{%
    \AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{bottomrule}}
  \IfLayerAtPageStyle{@everystyle@}{rightrule}{}{%
    \AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{rightrule}}
}
\newcommand*\RemoveRulesFromPageStyles{%
  \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{@everystyle@}{bottomrule,rightrule}%
}
```

Note that page style `@everystyle@` is special: its layers are part of all layer page styles.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  titlepage,
  ngerman,
  footheight=15pt,
  headheight=15pt,
  oneside% seems to be a onesided layout
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrhack}% <- added
\usepackage{pdflscape}% <- added
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[page]{totalcount}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
     total={170mm,257mm}
 }
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}

%% footer
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength\footheight{15pt}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ifoot*{\pagemark}
\cfoot*{Center}
\ofoot*{Right}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\small}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\small}

\renewcommand\pagemark{{%
    \textbf{\MakeUppercase{\pagename}}
    \usekomafont{pagenumber}%
    \thepage/\totalpages
}}

%% rules on every page
\DeclareNewLayer[
    background,
    bottommargin,
    addvoffset=-\footheight,
    addvoffset=-.5ex,
    mode=picture,
    contents=\putUL{\textcolor{Silver}{\rule[-\layerheight]{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}}
]{bottomrule}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=bottomrule,
    textarea,
    voffset=0pt,
    height=\paperheight,
    addhoffset=\textwidth,
    addhoffset=1ex
]{rightrule}
\newcommand*\AddRulesToPageStyles{%
  \IfLayerAtPageStyle{@everystyle@}{bottomrule}{}{%
    \AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{bottomrule}}
  \IfLayerAtPageStyle{@everystyle@}{rightrule}{}{%
    \AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{rightrule}}
}
\newcommand*\RemoveRulesFromPageStyles{%
  \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{@everystyle@}{bottomrule,rightrule}%
}
\AddRulesToPageStyles

%% logo on the title page
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=rightrule,
    contents=\putUL{\raisebox{-\height}{\makebox[5mm][r]{\includegraphics[scale=.7]{example-grid-100x100bp}}}}
]{titlepagelogo}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlepagelogo}
%%

\definecolor{rubgray}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{rubblue}{HTML}{003560}
\definecolor{rubgreen}{HTML}{8dae10}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \thispagestyle{titlepage}
  \begin{center}
    \vspace*{4cm}
    {\Huge \textbf{ \textcolor{rubgray}{ABSCHLUSSBERICHT}}}
    \\
    \vspace*{1cm}
    {\Large \textbf{ \textcolor{rubblue}{Funktionsweise und Datenschutzgefährdung der Smart Border Systeme}}}
    \\
    \vspace*{2cm}
    Abschlussbericht der Projektarbeit für das Fach\\
    \textbf{Datenschutz WS 16/17}\\
    Im Studienfach\\
    \textbf{    B.Sc. Angewandte Informatik}
  \end{center}
  \vfill
  \begin{flushright}
    \textbf{Saif Al-Dilaimi (xxx)} \\
    \textcolor{rubblue}{\textbf{RUHR-UNIVERSITÄT} BOCHUM} \\
    Institut für Neuroinformatik \\
    Ruhr-Universität Bochum \\
    Universitätsstraße 150 \\
    44801 Bochum
  \end{flushright}
\end{titlepage}

\blinddocument
\begin{landscape}
\RemoveRulesFromPageStyles
\Blindtext
\end{landscape}
\AddRulesToPageStyles
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for not providing a MWE but you were right and thats exactly what I want. Ty so much! Is it maybe possible to move footer - and its text (page number etc.) - on landscape from left to the bottom gray area? Is it also possible to move the left gray area to the right on landscape?

Comment: This will be possible by declaring new layer page styles. But I think the result would be really ugly if you print your document ...

Comment: Oh which part do you mean? Moving the left gray area  or moving the footer text down?

Comment: Both. If somebody reads/scrolls the printed book then the bottom rule jumps to the top and the footer entries to the right margin ... I do not recommend to change the normal layout in that way, especially if the document should be printed.